# Wordpress inside Laravel Public folder

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

I would like to show some of the not so important content pages from Wordpress for my laravel app.

I have installed Wordpress in `public/pages` folder of my laravel application.

The problem I am facing however is that pretty links (laravel.app/pages/sample-page) are throwing 404, as they are handled by laravel.

How can I fix this? I am assuming it has be to handled on nginx configuration file.

The site is hosting on Laravel Forge, and here's the nginx configuration file:

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/laravel.app/before/*;

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name .laravel.app;
    root /home/forge/laravel.app/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/laravel.app/264952/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/laravel.app/264952/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'xxx';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/laravel.app/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/laravel.app-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/laravel.app/after/*;
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would install the wordpress into it's own folder outside of the Laravel project and use nginx to configure a location for pages
something like

```
location ^/pages/index.php(/.*)?$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/pages/index.php)(/.+)$;
    OTHER CONFIG
}

location /pages/ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^.*$ /pages/index.php last;
        }
     OTHER CONFIG
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking around, and trying a few of the variations available - Here's a working nginx configuration:

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/laravel.app/before/*;

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name .laravel.app;
    root /home/forge/laravel.app/public;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/laravel.app/264952/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/laravel.app/264952/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'XXX';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/laravel.app/server/*;

    location /blog/index.php(/.*)?$ {        
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blog/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1000;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location /blog/ { 
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^.*$ /blog/index.php last;    
            }
        try_files $uri $uri/ blog/index.php?args; 
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/laravel.app-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/laravel.app/after/*;
```